# Expression for ICollection<T>.Any(Func<T, bool>)

Tags: c#, linq

Let's assume I have following Models:

```
public class Department
{
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to build an `Expression` for this:

```
departments.Where(x => x.Employees.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("foo")))
```

I have following code:

```
var departmentParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Department), "x");
PropertyExpression departmentListProperty = { x.Departments } // Value of the Expression shown in the debugger, actual code is some property helper to get the property by Name
var employeeParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "y");
PropertyExpression employeeNameProperty = { y.Name } // Same as departmenListProperty
var employeeNameContainsString = Expression.Call(employeeNameProperty, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(token));
var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(employeeNameContainsString, employeeParameterExpression).Compile();

var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2 &&  x.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Employee));

var containsEmployeeWithSearchString = Expression.Call(departmentListProperty, anyMethod, Expression.Constant(compiledExpression);
```

Running the last line, gives me following error:

`Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance. Parameter name: instance`

When I just have `.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static)` I don't get any `Any()`-Method unfortunately.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as the error message is telling you, when you're invoking a static method, you can't provide an instance of an object for the method to be invoked; you need to provide `null` for the implicit parameter.

Comment: Which implicit parameter do you mean?

Comment: @StefanSchmid The only one?  When you call a method you call it on an instance...if it's an instance method, which `Any` is not, it's a `static` method.  So, exactly as the error message says, when you pass in the instance to call the method on, you need to pass in `null`.

Comment: You mean like this ```Expression.Call(null, anyMethod, Expression.Constant(compiledExpression);```?

Comment: @StefanSchmid Yes, although you need to pass the sequence in in the parameter list, because `Any` accepts two parameters, not one.

Comment: I have ```Expression.Call(null, anyMethod, departmentListProperty, Expression.Constant(compiledExpression);``` now which looks the same to @D Stanley 's code. Is this theoretically correct?

Comment: @StefanSchmid Try it and find out.

Comment: It finally works. Removing the ```.Compile()``` to have the real lambda in there did the trick with your suggestions. Thanks! Also thanks to @DStanley for visualizing how it should be.

Answer (score 6):

`Any` and `Where` are extension methods on `Enumerable` and thus are `static` by definition.  The *actual* expression you are trying to build would be equivalent to:

```
Enumerable.Where(departments, 
                 x => Enumerable.Any(x.Employees,
                                     y => y.Name.Contains("foo")
                                     )
                )
```